# How to build a model for temperature-outcome using dlm?

Tags: r, regression, lag, rscript

I have a dataset containing information about weather, air pollution and healthoutcomes. I want to regress temperature (T) and temperature lag (T1) against cardiac deaths (CVD). I have previously used the glm model in R using the following script:

```
#for mean daily temperature and temperature lags separately.
modelT<-glm(cvd~T, data=datapoisson, family=poisson(link="log"), na=na.omit)
```

I get the effect estimates and standard error values which i used to convert to risk ratio.

Now i want to use dynamic linear model or distributed linear model for check the predictor-outcome and lagged predictor outcome association. However, i can't find the script for running the model in R.

I installed the DLM package in R, but still can't figure out how to build a model using DLM package in R.

I would appreciate if someone can help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try least squares multiple regression to predict the outcome? I used that method when I tried to 'predict' which factors influenced power in a floating offshore wind turbine. It is good for correlating multiple parameters.

They fit a plane to a set of points, but it seems like a similar idea.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99299/best-fitting-plane-given-a-set-of-points

Comment: Thank you Wilson. As DLM is the most widely used epidemiological technique so thats why i want to focus and learn DLM first